# Java elasticsearch API with Elasticsearch server on WM machine

Tags: java, api, elasticsearch, kibana

I do a query on Elasticsearch from Kibana 4.4.1 which looks like this :

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "FALK0911622560T",
          "analyze_wildcard": true
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {
                "@timestamp": {
                  "gte": 1438290000000,
                  "lte": 1440968400000,
                  "format": "epoch_millis"
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "must_not": []
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "2": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "@timestamp",
        "interval": "1w",
        "time_zone": "Europe/Helsinki",
        "min_doc_count": 1,
        "extended_bounds": {
          "min": 1438290000000,
          "max": 1440968400000
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "1": {
          "percentiles": {
            "field": "Quantity",
            "percents": [
              50
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This piece of code will return all the docs with "ProductCode" = FALK0911622560T", between the given interval.

I tried the same thing with Elasticsearch Java API with the following code :

```
        BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery(matchQueryKey,matchQueryValue));

        SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch(indexName)
                .setTypes(indexTypeName)
                .setQuery(boolQueryBuilder)
                .setSize(100)
                .addAggregation(AggregationBuilders
                        .dateHistogram("myHistogram")
                        .field("@timestamp")
                        .interval(DateHistogramInterval.WEEK)
                        .timeZone("Europe/Helsinki")
                        .minDocCount(1)
                        .extendedBounds(1438290000000L, 1440968400000L))
                .addFields(fieldsOfInterest)
                .execute()
                .actionGet();

        response.getAggregations();
```

But I get all the documents in the index with "ProductCode" = FALK0911622560T.

Between the given time, I should have only 5 documents on response.getAgregations() because I set the interval to be Week.

A doc in Elasticsearch looks like this :

```
{
  "_index": "warehouse-550",
  "_type": "core2",
  "_id": "AVOKCqQ68h4KkDGZvk6b",
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "message": "5,550,67.01,FALK0911622560T,2015-07-31;08:00:00.000\r",
    "@version": "1",
    "@timestamp": "2015-07-31T06:00:00.000Z",
    "path": "D:/Programs/Logstash/x_testingLocally/processed-stocklevels-550-25200931072015.csv",
    "host": "EVO385",
    "type": "core2",
    "Quantity": 5,
    "Warehouse": "550",
    "Price": 67.01,
    "ProductCode": "FALK0911622560T",
    "Timestamp": "2015-07-31;08:00:00.000"
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      1438322400000
    ]
  },
  "highlight": {
    "ProductCode": [
      "@kibana-highlighted-field@FALK0911622560T@/kibana-highlighted-field@"
    ],
    "message": [
      "5,550,67.01,@kibana-highlighted-field@FALK0911622560T@/kibana-highlighted-field@,2015-07-31;08:00:00.000\r"
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1438322400000
  ]
}
```

Please help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not add the `rangeQuery`. Change your `boolQueryBuilder` to following:

```
BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery(matchQueryKey,matchQueryValue)).must(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("@timestamp").gte(fromValue).lte(toValue));
```

You can get buckets using:

```
InternalDateHistogram histogram = searchResponse.getAggregations().getAsMap().get(aggregation_name);
List bucketList = histogram?.getBuckets()
```

Comment: could you help me how to extract the docs within that bucket ? Unfortunately I can't because I have under 15 points of reputation :(

Comment: Edited my answer as per your requirement. You can accept the answer as you are the owner of this question. Read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Well, thank you again for your quick response. I'm noob on stackoverflow, I mean this was my first question, hope you understand me. Wish you a beautiful day !

Comment: No its fine. Thanks:)